# wasm-bindgen - possible to identify build version / date?

Tags: wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

With webapplications the dev loop [change -> build -> deploy -> test] is very iterative. Due to browser caches easy to mistake the build version. Hence very often neccesary to identify the build version.

Does `wasm-bindgen`/`wasm-pack` provide some macro with e.g. `Timestamp` to dump in the logfile, in order to identify the version of the build?

Something like: `log(BUILD_DATE)` => `"2020:09:12 09:37:12"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `wasm-bindgen`/`wasm-pack` is actually nice integrated with cargo build tool chain.

So works with no tweaks.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html

[Passing symbol values to the Rust compiler during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549943/passing-symbol-values-to-the-rust-compiler-during-build)

With just the raw epoch-secs `build.rs` becomes

```
use std::time;

fn main() {
    let now = time::SystemTime::now()
        .duration_since(time::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap();

    println!("cargo:rustc-env=BUILD_INFO={}", now.as_secs());
}
```